# Unable to move file because it's being used by another process -- my program?

Tags: c#, file, directory

My program is unable to `File.Move` or `File.Delete` a file because it is being used "by another process", but it's actually my own program that is using it.

I use `Directory.GetFiles` to initially get the file paths, and from there, I process the files by simply looking at their names and processing information that way. **Consequently all I'm doing is working with the strings themselves, right?** Afterwards, I try to move the files to a "Handled" directory. Nearly all of them will usually move, but from time to time, they simply won't because they're being used by my program.

Why is it that most of them move but one or two stick around? Is there anything I can do to try freeing up the file? There's no streams to close.

Edit Here's some code:

```
public object[] UnzipFiles(string[] zipFiles)
    {
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); //not sure of proper array size, so using arraylist
        string[] files = null;

        for (int a = 0; a < zipFiles.Length; a++)
        {
            string destination = settings.GetTorrentSaveFolder() + @"\[CSL]--Temp\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFiles[a]) + @"\";
            try
            {
                fz.ExtractZip(zipFiles[a], destination, ".torrent");

                files = Directory.GetFiles(destination, 
                    "*.torrent", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                for (int b = 0; b < files.Length; b++)
                    al.Add(files[b]);
            }

            catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }

        try
        {
            return al.ToArray(); //return all files of all zips
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is called from:

```
try
                {
                    object[] rawFiles = directory.UnzipFiles(zipFiles);
                    string[] files = Array.ConvertAll<object, string>(rawFiles, Convert.ToString);
                    if (files != null)
                    {
                        torrents = builder.Build(files);
                        xml.AddTorrents(torrents);
                        directory.MoveProcessedFiles(xml);
                        directory.MoveProcessedZipFiles();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                { }
```

Therefore, the builder builds objects of class Torrent. Then I add the objects of class Torrent into a xml file, which stores information about it, and then I try to move the processed files which uses the xml file as reference about where each file is.

Despite it all working fine for most of the files, I'll get an IOException thrown about it being used by another process eventually here:

```
public void MoveProcessedZipFiles()
    {
        string[] zipFiles = Directory.GetFiles(settings.GetTorrentSaveFolder(), "*.zip", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        if (!Directory.Exists(settings.GetTorrentSaveFolder() + @"\[CSL] -- Processed Zips"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(settings.GetTorrentSaveFolder() + @"\[CSL] -- Processed Zips");

        for (int a = 0; a < zipFiles.Length; a++)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Move(zipFiles[a], settings.GetTorrentSaveFolder() + @"\[CSL] -- Processed Zips\" + zipFiles[a].Substring(zipFiles[a].LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to post some code - particularly that where you look at the file names. You must be inadvertently opening the file somehow.

Comment: *I process the files*, could you post some sample code about this processing, I sense there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Can you write a 10 line or so complete running program that reproduces the error you are experiencing? Try cutting out all the code that has no relevance to the problem and see if the error still happens. If so, post that code here.

Comment: How do you know they are being used by your program?

Comment: run "process explorer" from SysInternals and search for the name of your file to be sure that your application is holding a handle to it.

Comment: Are you running Indexing Service on that directory?

Comment: @Hans while your comment quite makes sense, any solution that involves disabling the antivirus (or opening any other vulnerability) makes me choke.  
@joslinm Hans's comment highlights the possibility that the AV (or something else) is just processing it when you try to move it. Consider adding the failed files to a queue, then sleep for a second or so and retry them (even better: use a longer delay after each try). If the queue remains unchanged for three or so consecutive retry's, then fail graciously (with an error message or the like).

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. 
@herenvardo: My program already does try to sleep for a little while, and then do it again. This fails, and I do throw an error message. Yet it doesn't make sense.
@Keith & @Daniel: Thanks, I found out it definitely is my program: http://i44.tinypic.com/vz818h.jpg (That's my program)
@Mark & @Darin: While I would love to, the processing is rather long code-wise, and does nothing but deal with the array of strings (which is why I wanted to make sure). I've tried reproducing just the `Directory.GetFiles` and `File.Move` unsuccessfully. I'll keep looking 4 code2show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, this really smells like a handle leak. Then, looking at your code, the `fz.ExtractZip(...)` looks like the best candidate to be using file handles, and hence be leaking them.

Is the type of `fz` part of your code, or a third party library? If it's within your code, make sure it closes all its handles (the safest way is via `using` or `try`-`finally` blocks). If it's part of a third party library, check the documentation and see if it requires any kind of cleanup. It's quite possible that it implements `IDisposable`; in such case put its usage within a `using` block or ensure it's properly disposed.

The line `catch(Exception e) {}` is horribly bad practice. You should only get rid of exceptions this way when you know exactly what exception may be thrown and *why* do you want to ignore it. If an exception your program can't handle happens, it's better for it to crash with a descriptive error message and valuable debug information (eg: exception type, stack trace, etc), than to ignore the issue and continue as if nothing had gone wrong, because an exception means that *something has definitely gone wrong*.

Long story short, the quickest approach to debug your program would be to:

1. replace your generic `catch`ers with `finally` blocks
2. add/move any relevant cleanup code to the `finally` blocks
3. pay attention to any exception you get: where was it thrown form? what kind of exception is it? what the documentation or code comments say about the method throwing it? and so on.
4. Either
   4.1. If the type of `fz` is part of your code, look for leaks there.
   4.2. If it's part of a third party library, review the documentation (and consider getting support from the author).

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, the FastZip library is a third party, and in my code is denoted by fz.

Thanks for the help and constructive criticism. I did have breakpoints there, and was usually holding the try catch so I can see where it went wrong and see if I can trace it  back.

I've considered the FastZip library, but the problem is, that's when my program handles zips. Unfortunately it also handles lone files, and I run into the same exact problem. I've tried both.

Comment: I've just realized that I use `Path.GetFileName` while processing the files, and this creates a file handle. Though I've tried reproducing this, and have been unsuccessful so far..

Answer (score 0):

What this mean: "there is no streams to close"? You mean that you do not use streams or that you close them?
I believe that you nevertheless have some opened stream.
Do you have some static classes that uses this files?
1. Try to write simple application that will only parse move and delete the files, see if this will works.
2. Write here some pieces of code that works with your files.
3. Try to use unlocker to be sure twice that you have not any other thing that uses those files: http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/ (don't forget check files for viruses :))

Comment: I think I may have a static class that uses the file! I'll check it out! I mean, I don't open a `FileStream` to handle the files. I have made a simple application in trying to reproduce the issue that pulled the file paths into a string array, did small operations on each string in the array, and then moved all the file paths from the string array. This worked fine, which points to something else in my processing like Darin pointed out

Answer (score 0):

Class `Path` was handling multiple files to get me their filenames. Despite being unsuccessful in reproducing the same issue, forcing a garbage collect using `GC.Collect` at the end of the "processing" phase of my program has been successful in fixing the issue.

Thanks again all who helped. I learned a lot.

Comment: Don't try to "fix" such problems with a `GC.Collect` (see e.g. http://henbo.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!2E073207A544E12!273.entry). It might work ok for your app, but you need to learn to manage resources correctly. And pelase don't let these "everything you do is wrong" comments stop you asking questions ;)

Comment: Haha, I'll try not to! :D 

Not to pester you, and I don't think qualifies as a brand new question.. but can you link me to any good resources on how to handle resources properly? I've tried looking around and most of the admittedly boggle me. 

I've looked into subclassing IDisposable, but then got subsequently confused about how/what to use a `private IntPtr handle;`. My confusion stems from this line of thought:
1.)I'm just trying to find out the filename using `Path`. 
2.)How can I use `Path` with `IntPtr`?

Plenty of other things confuse me.. so a good tutorial would be helpful :]